# Access a node in a xml using Sax parsing

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Am trying to parse a xml file ..and trying to read the employee nodes...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees>
  <employee id="111">
    <firstName>Rakesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Mishra</lastName>
    <location>Bangalore</location>
    <secretary>
        <employee id="211">
            <firstName>Andy</firstName>
            <lastName>Mishra</lastName>
            <location>Bangalore</location>
        </employee>
    </secretary>
  </employee>
  <employee id="112">
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Davis</lastName>
    <location>Chennai</location>
  </employee>
  <employee id="113">
    <firstName>Rajesh</firstName>
    <lastName>Sharma</lastName>
    <location>Pune</location>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

And in my handler ..I have the below...

```
    class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler{


@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if(qName.equals("employee")){           
        System.out.print("Its an employee ...and not an Secretary");
        /*for(int i=0;i< attributes.getLength();i++){
            System.out.print("Attr " +attributes.getQName(i)+ " Value " +attributes.getValue(i));
        }*/
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

How can i know if the the employee is a secretary or not

Regards

Comment: it's not the way sax works. you're trying to access nodes like it was a DOM parser. You have to keep variables in memory to know when you entered or left a node and check for other tags such as secretary (or not)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another `if` inside `startElement` to detect the `secretary` start element event, and set a flag that you can test when you are inside the `employee` tag. Then you reset the flag when you leave the `secretary` element. For example

```
class SaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

     private boolean insideSecretaryTag = false;

     @Override
     public void startElement(...) throws SAXException {

         if(qName.equals("employee")){           
             if(insideSecretaryTag) {
                // this is a secretary
             } else {
                // not a secretary
             }
         }

         if(qName.equals("secretary")){           
             insideSecretaryTag = true;
         }

     public void endElement(...) {
        if(qName.equals("secretary")){           
            insideSecretaryTag = false;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..but in this case its a sample xml and only 1 node is repeating..in case of a valid usecase which has multiple tags repeating..wont this kind be a cumbersome way of check?

Comment: If you use SAX, which is sequential processing, you will have to keep track of the occurrences using flags, objects, lists, whatever you need to save the parts you are interested in. SAX does not save anything to memory. It just causes events, which you capture in the handler methods. SAX is useful if you don't have to load the whole file and only need some parts of it. If your application has to deal with data from many tags, perhaps you should use DOM which will load all your XML into memory. With dom you can navigate the nodes and use XPath.

Comment: Yeah even with DOM... when i try checking it for below it says value as 4 which is not correct...                                          `System.out.println("No of employees without secretary "+ document.getElementsByTagName("employee").getLength());`

Comment: With DOM you have to first get a secretary: `Element secretary = document.getElementsByTagName("secretary").item(0);` For each `secretary` node you get the `employee` inside: `secretary.getChildren(0)` or `secretary.getElementsByTagName("employee")`